# Why am I only getting default values when adding something to my database? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to add tasks to my todo list. All of my added tasks are listed on the homepage (home.html) but whenever I try to add something it always sets my input to default (I added a picture at the end). I know I wrote 'default_value' in views but I wanted to check if it's even adding todos without it throwing an error.

**views.py**

```
def newTodo(request):
    obj = List()
    obj.taskText = request.POST.get("taskText", "default_value")
    obj.taskDate = request.POST.get("taskDate", "default_value")
    obj.taskDerc = request.POST.get("taskDerc", default= 5)
    obj.save()
    mydict = {
        "all_tasks" : List.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'newTodo.html', context=mydict)
```

**newTodo.html** (using Bootstrap)

```
<tbody>
                        {% block content %}
                            <tr>
                                <form action="{% url 'newTodo' %}">  
                                    <td scope="row">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskText" name="taskText"></td>
                                    <td scope="row">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskDate" name="taskDate"></td>
                                    <td scope="row">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskDerc" name="taskDerc"></td>
                                    <td><a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                            <path d="M10.97 4.97a.75.75 0 0 1 1.07 1.05l-3.99 4.99a.75.75 0 0 1-1.08.02L4.324 8.384a.75.75 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.094 2.093 3.473-4.425a.267.267 0 0 1 .02-.022z" />
                                            </svg>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </form>
                            </tr>
                        {% endblock %}
                     </tbody>
```

What am I missing? Any kind of help is appreciated!

[image]

**EDIT/UPDATE**
I fixed it myself. apparently, you can't use this table from bootstrap I used in newTodo.html, at least not in this form. It couldn't find any inputs so it always used the default_value.
I also changed

```
<form action="{% url 'newTodo' %}">
```

to

```
<form action="{% url 'submit' %}" method="get">
```

Because whenever I clicked on newTodo.html it automatically generated a new todo instead of only doing so when adding inputs.
I changed "newTodo" in views.py to "submit" and some other stuff, but yeah, that's it in general.

Comment: How about using Django's form API? see this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#the-view

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but try to replace those lines of code in your file `newTodo.html` :

```html
<a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><!–– your SVG ––></a>
```

by something like

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><!–– your SVG ––></button>
```

I think you currently have no way to *submit* the data in your form, you need a `button` of `type` "*submit*" for the data to be sent to the URL of the form (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Button#type) for more details).

This does not directly answer your question but by the way, here are some tips to improve your code:

- Don't name your model `List`, it could lead to confusion with Python's `list()` built-in which returns a `list`,
- Check that the request is a POST request before trying to access `request.POST`, or you could get a `500 internal server error`. Use the decorator `require_POST()` for instance (cf. [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/topics/http/decorators/)),
- Add a CSRF token `{% csrf_token %}` to your HTML form and make it mandatory in the POST request, for instance by adding the decorator `@requires_csrf_token` to your view (check [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/) for more information about CSRF in Django),
- Finally, as suggested in the comment of @Erik Kalkoken, you should use [Django's form API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/stable/topics/forms/) as much as possible and avoid building your forms from scratch. It will save you hours of work and it will be much cleaner.

Comment: thanks for helping! I did indeed change the url to submit. I wish I would've seen your answer earlier, haha. I also added {% csrf_token %} like you suggested. I edited my question and added my solution but should I still accept your answer? I don't know how this works, I haven't been on stackoverflow long enough to know. thanks again!